# CSS - How to stretch div height from top to bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors, styled-components

everyone.

So I am using Next.Js to create my app, however I have arrived at a problem.

In the picture and snippet below you can see how the page behaves right now, what I want is I want the pageContent div to have its height cover the page from the top to the bottom.

[image]

This is my CSS:

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(22, 22, 22);
  font-weight: 300;
}


* {
  outline: none !important;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


#__next{
    height: 100%;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    justify-content: center;
}

.pageContent{
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 100%;

    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

h1{
    color: rgb(221, 75, 31);
}
```

```html
<div id="__next">
  <div class="pageContent">
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just remove all `height: 100%` occurrences (if you can) and you should be good to go.

Comment: If you remove `height:100%;` and it doesn't work .. You can use `height: 100vh;`

Comment: Just remove ```height: 100%``` from ```#__next```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first remove the height and min-height properties from the html and body elements, and then set the height and min-height properties of the #__next element to 100% and 100vh, respectively. You should also set the height and min-height properties of the .pageContent element to 100% and 100vh, respectively.

```css
html, body{
  background-color: rgb(22, 22, 22);
  font-weight: 300;
}
#__next{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    justify-content: center;
}

.pageContent{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 80%;

    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience below is the general I follow for setting 100% height

- Give all element height 100%, except the last on which we want to set the height. That is give 100% to html and body tag also
- On the last element give min-height as 100% this will make sure that the container is a minimum 100% viewport.

Below is code snippet I just removed the height from pageContent

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(22, 22, 22);
  font-weight: 300;
}


* {
  outline: none !important;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


#__next{
    height: 100%;


}

.pageContent{
   
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

h1{
    color: rgb(221, 75, 31);
}
```

```html
<div id="__next">
  <div class="pageContent">
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
    <h1>asda</h1><h1>asda</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also I have removed the flex from #__next element because it was causing issue with height 100%, also I saw that it was being used for centering the content, The another way to center the content is by using margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto, this will also center pagecontent. Note: for this to work the pageContent must have set width. As in your css widht 80% was given.

Let me know if you have any query, happy to help.